# How to grep for a string using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I cannot seem to get this bash script to do what I want.

I have this in my bash script to show the problem:

```
GREP_TOTAL='"*** TOTAL *** .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*"'
echo "GREP_TOTAL:"
echo "$GREP_TOTAL"
echo `echo "$GREP_TOTAL"`
```

The output is:

```
GREP_TOTAL:
"*** TOTAL *** .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*"
"*** TOTAL Makefile product.mk test.mk inc src test .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*"
```

Obviously the string has been used to match content in my file system, and this is not what I want. I want to be able to grep for the line using back quotes like in the last line, say:

```
STR=`runSomeProgram | grep "$GREP_TOTAL"`
```

So in the shell this would be equal to:

```
runSomeProgram | grep "*** TOTAL *** .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It would help if you provide an example of the lines output by runSomeProgram that should match your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes

```
echo "`echo "$GREP_TOTAL"`"
```

Or, switch from `` `...` `` to `$(...)` for readability:

```
echo "$(echo "$GREP_TOTAL")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `TOTAL` word must be rounded by two `***` string and not whatever garbage, you probably want:

```
pattern="\*\*\* TOTAL \*\*\* .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*"
str=$(runSomeProgram | grep -- "$pattern")
printf "%s\n" "$str"
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a file called `new` that contains:

```
sh-4.3$ echo "*** TOTAL *** T5 Y7A 555" > new                                                                                                                                                                                                          
sh-4.3$ echo "*** TOTAL *** T5 Y7A 55" >> new
```

then in your script you must change this line

```
GREP_TOTAL='"*** TOTAL *** .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*"'
```

with

```
GREP_TOTAL='*** TOTAL *** .*[0-9] .*[0-9]* .*[0-9]*'
```

I've just removed the `""`

then within the script run `cat new | grep "${GREP_TOTAL}"`

the ouput is

```
*** TOTAL *** T5 Y7A 555                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
*** TOTAL *** T5 Y7A 55
```

Regards

Claudio

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: @Biffen grep "${GREP_TOTAL}" <yourFile> it's better?

Comment: Yes. The Wikipedia page has some details.